# Xcode 5.1 is not picking up external file changes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008) doesn't seem to pick up changes to an Objective-C
`.h` or `.m` file, whenever I edit it an with an external editor.  The
modified time stamp is set appropriately.  Is this some Xcode 5.1
configuration issue or a bug?